# GetAccount Not Found Error, is this Testnode Sync Issue?

Tags: eosio-code, eosio.token

I am testing the EOS SDK and have testnode running on my local,

it gives me an error

> Not Found, Exception

I have created an account from developer dashboard at testnode and using the accountname from there.

I'm getting this error on getAccount(chain/get_account) endpoint.

My Question is, Is this Testnode Sync Issue or I have to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

I can now Successfully get the result from getAccount(chain/get_account) endpoint.

I suppose this was the sync issue. You have to wait for some time and then it's available. Hope it works for someone else.